# Crash when linking a new label in Xcode IB

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I updated to Xcode 4.3.3 last night.  Today i tried to add another UILabel to a form.  To test things i even just copied and pasted an exact match to a label that is already there in the .h file and added a 2 at the end.  everything runs fine.  However once i link the label to the files owner and run, I get the following error.  How on earth can this be?

in the .h file  (accountNumText works great, but hooking up accountNumText2 kills it)

```
UILabel *accountNumText;
UILabel *accountNumText2;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *accountNumText;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *accountNumText2;
```

in the .m file

```
@synthesize patientNameText, accountNumText, accountNumText2;

- (void)dealloc
{

    [patientNameText release]; 
    [accountNumText release];
    [accountNumText2 release];
}
```

in IB i deleted everything and have just a view with 2 UILabels.  I hook one up to accountNumText save and run and it works great.  I hook the other to accountNumText and crash!

The only difference is that the accountNumText was there before I upgraded, and the accountNumText2 was added after.   HELP!

```
ERROR: thread 1: signal SIGABRT

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
    [pool release];
    return retVal;
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the crash you're getting

Comment: Breakpoint on all exceptions, please.

Comment: Thats the weird thing.  plus up the "signal SIGABRT" error with highlighted on the "int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil); line above.   also,  the log file where the details are show very little.  it says: argc = (int) 1,   argv = (char **)0xbffff51c.  Finally,  nothing to breakpoint,  it crashes before it loads up.

Comment: What does it say in your log?